# Injecting spring service in external groovy class created at runtime

Tags: java, spring, groovy, groovyshell, groovyclassloader

I have an Spring-powered app and want to integrate groovy. Specifically, I have one abstract java class with a set of abstract method definitions and one repository inyected with autowired.

This class must be implemented by several final groovy external classes (one for each client).

At this moment, I am calling the Groovy class in java this way:

```
final Class parsedClass = groovyClassLoader.parseClass(groovyFile);
final GroovyObject groovyObject = (GroovyObject) parsedClass.newInstance();
final Object response = groovyObject.invokeMethod(methodName, methodParameters);
```

The problem is that I need to autowired the repository variable in each Groovy external class but currently are null.

How can I notify the Groovy class to get the inyected repository variable when I create it at runtime?

Thanks!

**Edit**

Y have solved it using the setProperty method from groovyObjectObject this way:

```
groovyObject.setProperty("myRepository", myRepositoryImpl);
```

Answer (score 1):

The instance here is not created by spring, hence I don't think spring can automagically set the instance of repository in the `groovyObject` that you have.

However, if you can can `autowire` the repository into the class thats generating the `groovyObject` then you can manually inject the repo in the `newInstance` call.

`parsedClass.newInstance(repository:your_autowired_repo_ref)`

Comment: Hi kunal, the groovy.lang.GroovyObject class has not newInstance method with parameters, only a non-parameter method so I cannot do that this way.

Comment: I tried it with a contrived example and it worked. `class Person {def name}` `def p = Person.class.newInstance(name:"test")` and then `assert 'test'==p.name`

Comment: You are using the `Person.class.newInstance(name:"test")` with Groovy sintax (because you think I make the call from a .groovy class) but in my case the call is made from a .java class so I am limited to the `groovy.lang.GroovyObject'`java package (I am using groovy-all dependency from `org-codehaus.groovy`), which has only one new instance method with no parameters

Comment: Got that, makes sense to me now :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using the setProperty method from groovyObjectObject this way:

```
groovyObject.setProperty("myRepository", myRepositoryImpl);
```